# Efficient way to return top 10% of unsorted RDD as another RDD in Spark?

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, apache-spark

Task: given some huge unsorted input dataset of `RDD[Int]`, return top 10% as another `RDD[Int]`.

Why is the output type `RDD[Int]` in the first place? It's because the input is so big so that even the top 10% does not fit into memory, which is the reason I cannot call

```
sc.makeRDD(input.top(0.1 * input.count()))
```

as the output would be "collected" to and exhaust driver memory.

This problem is usually handled by sorting the *entire* input, and then calling some type of `limit()`. But then this becomes really inefficient as

- at least two passes of entire dataset are made. (One to get the size of dataset, and the others involves sorting/...)
- I am really interested in the top 10%, not the remaining 90%.

Is there an efficient alternative?

Comment: By top 10% it sounds like you have some type of order. If so the best approach would be to sort everything and then use `limit`, as you said. Otherwise, how can you know what data is in the top 10%?

Comment: @Shaido, yes of course there is some `Ordering` associated with the type.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You want some kind of `Ordering` and yet you have an unsorted RDD. Why do you sample an sort ?

Comment: @eliasah: I have some RDD in random order, and I want to sort it by some `Ordering`. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dataframe operation call approxQuantile that could work for you and let's you give the allowable error.

```
rdd.toDF("num").approxQuantile("num", Seq(0.1), 0.05).rdd
```

Then anything on the rdd above that belongs approximately to your top 10% with a 5% error.

Comment: Thank you @ayplam ! What's the efficiency of space/time complexity of `approxQuantile`?

Comment: @K.Chen `O(log(xN))` where x is the approximate (0.1).